# java.security.AllPermission fails for Grails 1.3.2 app on JBoss 5.1 Community Edition

Tags: java, grails, jboss, securitymanager

From what I understand, a SecurityManager policy file with only

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

should grant all permissions globally. However, running a Grails 1.3.2 app on JBoss 5.1 Community Edition and JRE 6u24 gives the following stack trace when accessing a page after a successful start (while without the security manager turned on it runs fine), could this be a bug somewhere, or does anyone have any other insight?:

*I had to cut out about a 150,000 characters from the middle of the stacktrace, looks like some kind of infinite loop may have led to the ultimate PerGen exception:

```
2011-08-03 23:55:10,218 [ajp-127.0.0.1-8009-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Sanitizing stacktrace:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:95)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:342)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor346.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1003)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at gsp_todAdminTool_layoutsauthLayout_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_todAdminTool_layoutsauthLayout_gsp.groovy:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at gsp_todAdminTool_layoutsauthLayout_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_todAdminTool_layoutsauthLayout_gsp.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.executeClosure(GroovyPageTagBody.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.captureClosureOutput(GroovyPageTagBody.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.call(GroovyPageTagBody.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib.captureTagContent(SitemeshTagLib.groovy:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1003)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib$_closure3.doCall(SitemeshTagLib.groovy:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:342)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage$invokeTag$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at gsp_todAdminTool_layoutsauthLayout_gsp.run(gsp_todAdminTool_layoutsauthLayout_gsp.groovy:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:173)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet.renderPageWithEngine(GroovyPagesServlet.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet.doService(GroovyPagesServlet.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.processFilterChain(UrlMappingsFilter.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:248)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.doDispatch(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:446)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.access$000(ApplicationDispatcher.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher$PrivilegedForward.run(ApplicationDispatcher.java:80)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2011-08-03 23:55:14,921 [ajp-127.0.0.1-8009-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Sanitizing stacktrace:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.access$100(ApplicationDispatcher.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher$PrivilegedInclude.run(ApplicationDispatcher.java:96)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.includeForUrl(WebUtils.java:359)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.includeForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:322)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet$1.doFilter(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.doDispatch(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:446)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.access$000(ApplicationDispatcher.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher$PrivilegedForward.run(ApplicationDispatcher.java:80)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 1 more
```

**Update**

I filed a Grails bug report: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7845